# How do I establish peace between the Geth and the Quarians?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Legion is cool. Tali is also cool. I don't want to pick between them.

In ME2, I told the Quarians to not go to war, but they did so anyway.

It seems that it's not possible to stop the war from starting in ME3, but is there any way to end it in a way that doesn't involve total annihilation of one of the sides? I like Quarian Engineers *AND* Geth Infiltrators.

How do I unite the Geth and the Quarians against the Reapers?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In order to reconcile the Geth-Quarian War and gain the most out of the situation you need to score at least 5 points on the following list

**Mass Effect 2 Decisions**

- +2 for Tali is exonerated at her trial (eg NOT exiled)
- +2 for destroyed the heretics
- +1 for resolving the Tali/Legon conflict with a renegade or paragon solution

As noted [in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53757/10260), if you did not import a game and started a new mission in ME3 you will have saved Tali, Tali will have been exiled by her people and Legion was never activated and thus the heretic mission would have have appeared.  Ergo this avenue is closed if you started a new game file.

**Mass Effect 3 Decisions**

- +1 for Rannoch: Destroy the Geth Squadron on Rannoch (aka fighter base)
- +1 for Rannoch: Save the Admiral (not his men, the admiral)

You must also complete Legion's Mission in ME3 or the peace options will not be available.  You need a high reputation to get the Paragon/Renegade options to appear.

If you rewrote the heretics in ME2 instead of destroying them, and still manage to achieve peace, you'll get more war assets but there will be less Quarians.

Comment: Does Legion need to be alive for this? Or does "I am not Legion" Legion VI work just the same?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Do you mean for achieving the 3 ME3 missions?  Assuming you have at least 3 points from the ME2 chart?

Comment: Yes. In my scenario, I have Tali Exonerated and Resolved Conflict, but I rewrote the herectics *and* Legion died. Am I boned?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Not to pass the buck, but please let us know when you get there :)  I have a gut feeling that you're ok, it's me with the no-prior-save Shepard that's boned.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's not a lazy issue here :)  I don't have the appropriate save file.  I can track it down using a generator or what have you, but you've got save, try, reload :0

Comment: Well, *had*. I'd have to playthrough 2/3 of the game to get back there.

Comment: On my mission list, the two relevant ME3 missions are labeled as "Rannoch" instead of "N7"

Comment: You're right, oops.

Comment: Geth VI works just fine if you have sufficient points.  Science

Comment: And what if there is no ME2 save at all? I'm starting from scratch ME3. Any TODOs to get them both on the same page?

Comment: @HassanGulzar There is a question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/57710/10260 about that exact problem.

Answer (score 4):

The following instructions have worked well for me.

> For the best result you will want to do certain things in ME2 and in ME3 when you do Rannoch.
>   In ME2, you will need to get Tali found innocent in her trial, Destroy the Heretics in Legion's loyalty mission, and resolve Tali's and Legion's argument once their loyalty missions are done.
>   In ME3, save Admiral Zal Koris over the crew of his ship, take out the fighters, side with Admiral Han Gerrel when he is arguing with Admiral Ran on the Normandy over the radio about their portions of the fleet, Side with Tali when Admiral Xen wants to use some of the fleet to go through a Geth debris field for tech instead of saving escape pods. With those things done, you'll want to side with Legion and then when given the blue and red options, pick one of those to persuade the Admiral Han Gerrel to stop for a minute.

[Source](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/347/index/9687811/1)

Answer (score 1):

I got to this point with high reputation (>400 paragon) and +7 points worth of decisions across ME2 and ME3, and the compromise conversation options still did not appear.

So I opened up my save game in this save editor and the field for Rannoch points was set to 0 in spite of all the previous decisions:

https://www.moddb.com/games/mass-effect-3/downloads/mass-effect-3-save-editor1

It seems like the game bugged out somehow. I set the value back to 7 manually and then the compromise options appeared as expected.

Comment: Attention anyone reading this. This should be the accepted answer. I did EVERYTHING right and the save said zero so I didn't even get the prompt. It's definitely a bug of some sort.