# What was Tali's Paragon Interrupt?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just finished Priority: Rannoch.

> I chose to let the Geth upload the Reaper code, and the Quarians got wiped out. I was unable to get the Quarians and the Geth to make peace. At the end, Tali jumped off a cliff, and there was a Paragon Interrupt as Shepard walked toward Tali. It looked like Shepard was too far away to save Tali. I had set down the controller and couldn't activate the Interrupt in time.

What would that Paragon Interrupt have done?

Comment: Wow. Now I have to replay this game and purposely fail to make peace so that I can see this.

Comment: @MrSmooth it was...extremely dramatic.

Comment: I take it you didn't have enough rep for the charm option earlier?  I don't remember there being an interrupt near that point.

Comment: @MBraedley it's not a matter of rep, you have to have done some stuff in the previous game as well...and I didn't even play the last game.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the wiki page after writing that.  Seems like a much harder check then even the [Morinth](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Morinth) check, which is notoriously hard even with an imported save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih5bhxsI534#t=3m51s), the option is that you make a dive to try to catch her.

> But you miss.

Answer (score 3):

The interrupt only causes Shepard to try and save Tali, but he/she won't be able to catch Tali in time.

To save Tali and get both, the Geth and the Quarians on your side [see this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/how-do-i-unite-the-geth-and-the-quarians). If you do not meet the requirements to make peace between the Geth and the Quarians, e.g. because you didn't import a save, you cannot have the Geth join you and save Tali at the same time.

Comment: I've seen that Q, but I have an unimported save, so it's a no-go