# Is  Quarian and Geth peace possible without importing a ME2 save?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I unite the Geth and the Quarians?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/how-do-i-unite-the-geth-and-the-quarians)

Is it possible to achieve Quarian and Geth peace without importing a ME2 save? I know you need a paragon option to achieve this, but it's not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55359/10260) to understand why.

Comment: jeez, way to take all the credit for stephens answer...:P

Comment: Hardly. There's just little to add and it's an internal link here.