# Does punching (renegade) the Quarian admiral or participating in the smalltalk on Normandy affect Quarian/Geth peace?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect

I remember reading somewhere that if you support a general but then Tali during the on-board bantz, you can get a +1 to the ability to have Geth and Quarians join forces. Is this so?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/how-do-i-establish-peace-between-the-geth-and-the-quarians?rq=1