# What happened to the Female Krogan?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> I just finished Priority: Tuchanka where we were distributing the Genophage cure and Eve died at the end. I had Morden trick the Krogans and the Genophage won't be cured. Morden is alive.
>  Why did Eve die?

So...how the heck does this character die? I never saw anything to indicate she was wounded, except she was in the caravan when a ship crashed into it on Tuchanka. Other players have indicated she doesn't usually die.

If it matters, I've been doing a pure Paragon run until the spoilered decision, and I did not import a ME2 save.

What has science done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eve's death is related to whether you destroyed the data in Mass Effect 2. If the data was destroyed (or not discovered at all, via not having performed Mordin's Loyalty mission in ME2 at all), then Mordin has insufficient information to keep Eve alive -  she succumbs to her weakened immune system.

If Mordin has the data from ME2, then he is able to use this data to save Eve and keep her alive.

Incidentally, you can only successfully keep Mordin alive if Eve dies. If she lives, she will prevent you from successfully convincing Mordin to sabotage the cure.

Comment: Interesting, then the default state of ME3 forces Eve to die...I assume this is also related to the comments my squad made about how sick Eve looked?

Comment: @BenBrocka This answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53757/10260 notes that Mordin's Loyalty mission was not completed as part of a new character backstory.

Comment: Or more precisely, the combination of Wreav being much less of a moderate than Wrex would have been and not having Eve around as a stabilizing influence convinces him that the Krogan may not be ready to be cured yet.

Comment: that's not true. I have finished the ME series 3 times, and all times, i saved the data. The first time, wrex died so i dealt with wreve, eve died. the second time, wrex lived, eve lived. the thrid time, they both lived, and now, i'm on my fourth time, and even though wrex lived and i got the data, eve still died. I replayed it for hours, switching my team, (always had garrus and james) and no matter what i did, she died.