# Default Starting Conditions for new characters?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the backstory if you don't import a save?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53526/whats-the-backstory-if-you-dont-import-a-save)

What are the default starting conditions for new characters (non-imported) in Mass Effect 3? I would assume this question has come up somewhere before, but so far I haven't been able to find a concise answer.

I already read so much that the game assumes you made the dumbest of choices in ME2, so Jack is dead and no romancing Miranda in ME3. But what are the other conditions to look out for?

Comment: Garrus is alive, so the game assumes you made the only choice that matters :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No DLC, sidequests or Loyalty Missions are counted toward Mass Effect 3. This includes two DLC exclusive characters, Zaeed and Kasumi, who count as never being recruited.
- Tali is exiled from the Migrant Fleet.
- Shepard does not enter into any romantic relationships. Again.
- Grunt is not recruited.
- Legion is not recruited, and no choice is made for the Geth.
- Samara is never recruited. She is killed by Morinth trying to escape from Ilium.
- Suicide Mission Survivors: Mordin, Jacob, Garrus, Tali and Miranda.
- Suicide Mission Survivors (Normandy Crew): Joker and Chakwas. All other crew members are considered killed.
- Suicide Mission Deaths: Jack, and Thane.
- The Collector Base is destroyed.
- Although the DLC is not considered completed by Shepard, the events still occured. The Batarian System is destroyed, and Liara is the Shadow Broker.