# I cannot unite the Geth and Quarians, do I support Legion or Tali?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I started a new game in ME3 which means that I have already failed in the preconditions for uniting the Geth and Quarians.

> Tali or Legion is going to die.

Should I support Tali or Legion from a war assets/other game considerations point of view?

Comment: Morally, the Geth are innocent and the Quarians really aren't. War-asset-wise, I don't know. I think you need to keep Tali alive to get Defense Drone from her though.

Comment: I think the Geth fleet is more powerful because if Geth have Reaper upgrades then it's Reaper vs Reaper. Did you see how the Geth lasers ripped thru Quarian ships? Plus the Geth were innocent. They joined the Reapers because they would rather be slaves than go extinct. So my vote is with the Geth and not the Quarian fleet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you support the geth:

> Both Tali and Legion will die.

If you support the quarians:

> Only Legion dies.

Highest total possible war assets are provided below.  Numbers will change based on different factors.  Consult the wiki articles linked to get numbers based off your own choices.

## [Quarian war assets](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets/Quarian)

- Civilian fleet: 200 (base) + 50 (destroyed heretics) + 25 (rescued Admiral Koris) = 275
- Heavy fleet: 200 (base) + 25 (supported Admiral Gerrel) + 50 (destroyed heretics) + 5 (Allers interview) = 280
- Patrol fleet: 200 (base) + 50 (destroyed heretics) = 250
- Admiral Daro'Xen: 25 = 25
- **Total war assets: 830**

## [Geth war assets](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets/Geth)

- Corps: 300 (base) + 5 (Allers Interview) = 305
- Fleet: 300 (base) + 150 (rewrote heretics) + 5 (Allers interview) = 455
- Prime platoon: 60 (base)
- **Total war assets: 820**

Also consider that Tali will not be available for missions or to contribute her power to the medi-lab for you to use.

Comment: What are the impacts of the two choices from a war assets point of view?

Comment: @Stephen I'm looking for numbers at the moment, since I'm not sure.  I'll update when I find them

Comment: @Stephen It [looks like](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615759-mass-effect-3/62272061) the geth provide a bigger war asset contribution, but I'm still looking for a more credible source

Comment: I can confirm the Geth give those crazy war asset numbers.

Comment: I actually had missed a section from the wiki on the quarian assets.  They're actually closer than I first stated.  All of these numbers are dependent on plot choices, though.  Check the wiki to confirm with your own choices.

Comment: I was surprised Geth were worth so much more; makes sense they're pretty balanced though. By default were the Heretics destroyed or rewritten though?

Comment: @BenBrocka [Legion was never recruited](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55641/default-starting-conditions-for-new-characters) so that mission never happened.  I guess you don't get *either* war asset then?  I'm not sure

Comment: So other than war assets the next point is that I won't get Tali's ability in the medi bay if I go with Legion?

Comment: @Stephen That and the obvious fact that you won't be able to take her on missions.  I used her a lot, so that would have been a pretty bad result for me