# Did Zaeed Massani survive, and was he loyal, if I start a new game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the mission Citadel: Volus Ambassador the outcome depends, in part, on whether Zaeed Massani survived the events of ME2 and if he was loyal.

It's not entirely clear from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53757/10260) whether he will be present or not as I don't know if his missions were from DLC or N7 missions, having not played the other titles.

Did he survive and was he loyal if I don't import a saved game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No DLC on import means Zaeed and Kasumi were never recruited. You won't meet them at all in ME3 unless you recruited them in ME2.

Comment: Updated the other answer with this info.  Thx

Comment: I can confirm, it's like these characters never existed if you don't import.